# How to make django globally available

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

How can I make my Django project accessible via internet?

When I execute the project in Windows OS by typing with a disabled firewall it works and reachable via the internet.

But in Linux OS it does not. I tried the same actions. Executed it by typing and made sure my firewall is disabled

```
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The expected result is that project is accessible via the internet like in windows OS

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 1):

you must deploy your app in one server. I recommend you pay for one VPS like digitalocean. And dont run you app with runserver. Runserver is only for development. Use one wsgi like gunicorn.

If you not want pay for this service. You can use heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

I recommend use docker. Docker possibilite you development and deploy same envoriment